# How to get the exams dates with WebUntis?

Tags: api, json-rpc

I am currently working with the WebUntis JSON-RPC API and would like to use it to retrieve dates from the examinations. Is this possible for a specific student or class? Because the documentation only lists one method for all students (getExams), but as a student you have no access to it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it look like, there is no other method to get the exams.
But you can try to scrape the exams of the particular class from the webuntis website.

I created a web-scraper which looks for the yellow background-color if there is a test.
The Web-Scraper returns all subjects of exams this week. But you can extend it to return much more information...

https://gist.github.com/jstrausd/a6a0a0eea147f0bb70c9ea27b814d502

Comment: I updated the gist, so now the scraper also scrapes the date and time of the exam